# Hollow Square in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am having trouble with the following MIPS assembly code, What I want to do is take the following C code and make this in MIPS Assembly(MARS 4.5).

```
    /* Input number of rows from user */
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    /* Iterate over each row */
    for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        /* Iterate over each column */
        for(j=1; j<=N; j++)
        {
            if(i==1 || i==N || j==1 || j==N)
            {
                /* Print star for 1st, Nth row and column */
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        /* Move to the next line/row */
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So far this is what I have accomplish for the MIPS code. I cant seen to understand how to implement the IF statements so that I can get a output like this:

```html
Enter number of rows: 5 
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

MIPS Code:
    main:

```
#prompt1 and read character
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall

#Getting user's input as text
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, userInput
    li $a1, 2   
    syscall

#prompt newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

#prompt and read int
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall


#read int and store in $t0
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0 #store n in $t0
    move $t1, $v0 #store n in $t1

    bge $v0, 3, proceed #if input is 0 or more, goto proceed otherwise display error message and goto exit              
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, errormsg
    syscall             

b exit

proceed:
#print n
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0   
    syscall
#prompt newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline

for1:
    beq $t3, $t0, end_for1
    addi $t3, $t3, 1 # Increment counter
    li $t4, 0   #reseting j to 0 after each iteration of the for loop

######################## Inner loop          
for2:
    beq $t4, $t1, end_for2
    addi $t4, $t4, 1 # Increment counter
    b for2  
end_for2:
######################## Inner loop 
    b for1
end_for1:   


exit:
    li $v0, 10  
    syscall

.end main
```

Comment: You don't even need to branch.  You can restructure it as `int cond = (i-2 > N-3) | (j-2 > N-3);  putchar(  '0' + ('*'-' ')*cond );` using unsigned compares (`sltu`) so i==1 means `i-2` wraps to a large unsigned number.  So you have the syscall once, but with different data depending on the condition.  Or you could special-case the first and last rows to simplify the main loop.  MARS has a print-char system call (like `putchar`) which you should use instead of needing a pointer to a string, if you aren't actually going to fill a string in memory and print it all at once.